# Show that Subgaussian norm of uniform distribution on l1 ball is not bounded by some constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, approximation, gamma-function, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to show that, for a given random vector $X$ with values from $1$ to $n$ that is uniformly distributed on $K$ for $K= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_1 \leq r \}$, $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|X\|_{\psi2} = \infty $$

Assuming that $r \approx n  $ is already proved.

The Question is from R. Vershynin High-dimensional probability Exercise 3.4.9 part b

**ATTEMPT:**

I want to show it by saying that $\|X_1\|_{L_p} \leq C \sqrt{p}$ does not hold.

$$\|X_1\|_{L_P}^{p} = \int_0^{\infty} p x^{p-1} P(|X_1| > x) = pr^p \frac{\Gamma(p) \Gamma(n+1))}{\Gamma(n+p+1)}  = p r^p \frac{\Gamma(p) n!}{(n+p)!}$$

However, I'm unable to simplify it beyond this to show that the above statement doesn't hold.

Comment: what do you mean by $ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||X||_{\psi2} = \infty $ ? what is $\psi2$? what is the dependence on $n$?

Comment: @uniquesolution $\psi2 $ is the subgaussian norm. and X is a random vector of variables from 1 to n.

Comment: Do you mean to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|X_1\|_{\psi_2} = \infty$?

Comment: @Semiclassical I made a mistake in defining K, I edited it now to be $\leq r $ instead of 1

Comment: @dmh wouldn't it also prove my claim if you're able to prove $ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||X_1||_{\psi2} = \infty $

Comment: Well, I don't know how to define $\|X\|_{\psi_2}$

Comment: @dmh do you have a way to prove it for $X_1$ ?

Comment: I don't think the question as stated is correct - if $r$ is fixed then the marginals of $X$ are bounded and so $X$ is bounded, meaning that $X$ is indeed sub-Gaussian. If $r$ grows with $n$ however, then the $\psi_2$ norm will depend on $n$ as well.

Comment: @WeakLearner The Question is from R. Vershynin High-dimensional probability Exercise 3.4.9, for reference.

Comment: See the question [Uniform distribution on $\ell_1$ ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475643/uniform-distribution-on-ell-1-ball), it is the same as yours. One can find the exact distribution of $X_1$ and show that $X_1$ is not subgaussian.

Comment: @Lose'CKi perhaps you are using an old version of the book/there is a problem with the question. As I said, if $r$ is fixed then the random variable is bounded and hence subgaussian.

Comment: In fact, looking at the most recent verrsion of the book requires $r \asymp n$

Comment: @WeakLearner yes I was able to prove part a, but I'm interested in proving part b. Does learning that r is approximately n, help in proving it ? and how?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer isnt that only in the case where $r$ grows with $n$? not in general. If $X_1$ is bounded it is of course SG.

Comment: @dmh Oh sorry, I didn't write that properly. I think I'll write an answer regarding the same, because the original answer there isn't the most comprehensive, and I would rather that this question be the duplicate target than that one.

Comment: @Lose'CKi my point is that if $r$ is constant, then $X$ is bounded and hence **is** subGaussian. You only get the claim in your question for an appropriate choice of $r$. In this case the question should actually be $r\asymp n$. You need to edit your question to include this information, as it stands your question is not well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that your attempt is different from the attempt in the other post (which is also kind of incomplete), so I'll address your question directly.

You want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|X^n_1\|_{\psi_2} = \infty$ where $X^n_1$ is the first coordinate of a uniform random vector $X^n$ over the unit $l_1$ ball in $\mathbb R^n$. As a consequence of this, we will also have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|X^n\|_{\psi_2} = \infty$, which is exactly what Vershynin 3.4.9(ii) dictates.

The way you want to show this is to show that "$\|X_1\|_p \leq C \sqrt{p}\ $ does not hold". Now, this statement isn't the most clear, which is causing the problem. Indeed, $X_1$ is bounded hence subgaussian. The problem is that the same $C$ doesn't work for all $n$, and hence the limit becomes infinite.

Perhaps, what you want to argue is this:

> There exists no finite constant $C$ such that for all $n \geq 1,p \geq 1$, $$
> \|X^n_1\|_{L^p} \leq C \sqrt{p}.
> $$
> An implication of this, is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|X^n_1\|_{\psi_2} = \infty$.

Now, there are two problems. The first I already highlighted, namely the unclear statement. The second is that the proof that the non-existence of $C$ implies the infinite limit of the subgaussian norms is actually something that requires a bit of work. It is not merely obvious from the definitions of subgaussianity.

Indeed, to prove the implication, you need to go to Proposition 2.5.2 of Vershynin. In there, you will realize that when you *don't* scale $K_2$ and treat it as some constant in condition (ii), then $K_2$ and the constant $K_4$ which is obtained in condition (iv) (and which determines the subgaussian norm $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}$) are related in such a way that if $K_2 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ (which is what will happen if the $L^p$ norm inequalities go through) then $K_4 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$(which is exactly the subgaussian norm going to infinity).

Thankfully, the proof of Proposition 2.5.2, when you look at it in detail, shows that $K_4$ is at least some constant times $K_2$, where this constant doesn't depend upon $n$. Therefore, the implication is actually true and I leave you to see that the relation between $K_2$ and $K_4$ is exactly as I described earlier.

---

With that in hand, let's look at $$
\|X^n_1\|^p_{L^p} = pr^p\frac{\Gamma(p)n!}{(n+p)!}
$$
We know that $r \approx n$ from part(i) of the same problem (we've been asked to assume such a value of $r$ for this part), so we can say that $$
\|X^n_1\|^p_{L^p} \geq Cpn^p\frac{\Gamma(p)n!}{(n+p)!}
$$
for some constant $C$ independent of $n$. The $L^p$ norm estimates that we want to show are equivalent to $$
\sup_{n \geq 1, p \geq 1} \frac{\|X^n_1\|_{L^p}}{\sqrt{p}} = \infty \iff \sup_{n \geq 1, p \geq 1} \frac{\|X^n_1\|^p_{L^p}}{\sqrt{p}^p} = \infty \iff \sup_{n \geq 1, p \geq 1} \frac{Cpn^p\Gamma(p)n!}{(n+p)!p^{p/2}} = +\infty
$$

At this point, a quick glance at fixing a value of $p$ (say $p=2$) and letting $n \to \infty$ will result in a failure, since the top and bottom will then be polynomials of the same degree in $n$. So $p$ needs to vary with $n$. Let us ignore the constant $C$ in the supremum : after all, it plays no role in determining the finiteness/infiniteness of the supremum.

However, the very next substitution idea works, which is $p=n$. Indeed, suppose you put $p=n$ to get $$
\frac{Cpn^p\Gamma(p)n!}{(n+p)!p^{p/2}} \to \frac{Cn^{n+1}\Gamma(n)n!}{(2n)!n^{n/2}} = \frac{n^{n+1-(n/2)}(n+1)!n!}{(2n)!} = (n+1)n^{(n/2)+1}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}
$$
You can now apply Stirling's approximation $$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{m!}{\sqrt{2\pi}m^{m+\frac 12}e^{-m}} = 1
$$

We call $f$ asymptotic to $g$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$ from now on.

As a consequence of Stirling's approximation, $(n!)^2$ is asymptotic to $2\pi n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}$ and $(2n)!$ is asymptotic to $\sqrt{2\pi}2^{2n+\frac 12}n^{2n+\frac 12}e^{-2n}$.

Taking their ratio, $\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}n^{\frac 12}}{4^n}$.

Thus, $(n+1)n^{(n/2)+1}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(n+1)n^{(n/2)+3/2}}{4^n}$. Since $n+1$ is asymptotic to $n$, the entire expression is asymptotic to $$
\frac{n^{n/2+5/2}}{4^n} = \exp\left((n/2+5/2)\log n -n\log 4\right)=\exp((n\log n)/2 - n \log 4 + 5\log n/2)
$$
Now, the expression inside the exponential operation goes to infinity as $n \to \infty$ because the dominating term is the $n \log n$ term. As a consequence of all the approximations we've made, it follows that $$
\sup_{n \geq 1} \frac{(n+1)n^{n/2+1}(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = \infty \implies \sup_{n \geq 1, p \geq 1} \frac{Cpn^p\Gamma(p)n!}{(n+p)!p^{p/2}} = +\infty \implies \sup_{n \geq 1, p \geq 1} \frac{\|X^n_1\|_{L^p}}{\sqrt{p}} = \infty,
$$
which is what you wanted to prove and which, by virtue of the argument connecting $K_2$ and $K_4$ that I spoke of earlier, shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|X^n_1\|_{\psi_2} = +\infty$ and hence $\|X^n\|_{\psi_2} = +\infty$.